# Как найти максимальное значение массива и запомнить под каким именно индексом он был?

Tags: c, массивы, индексы

Дан массив. Необходимо найти столбец с наибольшей длиной неубывающей последовательности чисел, в пределах столбца сверху вниз.
Я остановилась на моменте, когда знаю, в каком столбе хранится какая длина. Эти значения связаны массивом "forcount".

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 0; //колво горизонт
    int n = 0; //колво вертикаль
    
    
    scanf("%d%*c%d", &m, &n);
    int massiv[m][n];
    if (n!=1) {
    for(int t=0; t<m; t++) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            
            scanf("%d", &massiv[t][i]);
        }
    }
    
    }
    if (n==1) {
        for (int y = 0; y<m; y++) {
            scanf("%d", &massiv[y][0]);
        }
    }
    
    int forcount[m];
    int w = 0;
    while (w < n) { //иду по вертикаль
        int count = 1;
        for (int e = 0; e < (m-1); e++) { //иду по горизонтам
            int q = e+1;
            if (massiv[e][w] <= massiv[q][w]) { //если след элемент больше +1
                count++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            
        }
       
        forcount[w] = count;
        
        w++;
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
        if forcount[z]
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код не проверял, пишу прямо здесь.

Обратите внимание на имена переменных - я вот иногда забываю, что является шириной, а что высотой, если где-то далеко вверху они были названы m,n, да и к чему относятся индексы i,j - могу сбиться (для двумерных массивов обычно применяю ix, iy)

```
 int maxcount = 1;
 int colmax = 0;
 for (int col = 0; col < width; col++){
     int count = 1;
     for (int row = 1; row < height; row++){
        if (massiv[row][col] >= massiv[row-1][col]) {
            count++;
            if (count > maxcount) {
                maxcount = count;
                colmax = w;
            }
        }
        else 
          count = 1;
     }
 }
```